# TypeError : #1010 A term is undefined and has no properties at MethodInfo-258()

Tags: actionscript-3

please help me, i'm new at AS3
I have an Error when I compile my project, this is summary of my error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at com.greensock::TweenLite/init()
>       at com.greensock::TweenMax/init()
>       at com.greensock::TweenMax/renderTime()
>       at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
>       at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
>
> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>       at MethodInfo-258()

and this is my complete code that I use

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var tombolMenu:Array = [menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5, menu6, menu7, menu8, menu9];
var judulMateri:Array = [title_1,title_2, title_3, title_4, title_5, title_6, title_7, title_8, title_9]
var isiMateri:Array = [materi_1, materi_2, materi_3, materi_4, materi_5, materi_6,
                       materi_7, materi_8, materi_9]
var jumlahFrame:Array = [10, 5, 6, 8, 4, 9,5, 5, 5];
    TweenLite.from(bar_mc, 0.5, {x:5000});
    TweenLite.from(subject_mc, 0.5, {delay:1, x:1000});
    navi_mc.visible=false;
for (var i:int = 0; i< tombolMenu.length; i++){
    var gap:Number = i/4;
    var tombolMenunya = tombolMenu[i];
    tombolMenunya.buttonMode = true;
    //muncul menu
    TweenLite.from(tombolMenu[i], 0.5, {delay:gap, scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Circ.easeOut});
    tombolMenunya.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_menu_0);
    function fl_menu_0(e:MouseEvent):void{
        TweenLite.to(bar_mc, 0.5, {delay:1,x:5000});
        TweenLite.to(subject_mc, 0.5, { x:1000});
        for (var i:int = 0; i<= tombolMenu.length; i++){
            var gaps:Number = i/4;
            //menu hilang
            TweenMax.to(tombolMenu[i], 1,{delay:gaps,scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Circ.easeIn});

            //munculkan materi
            if (e.currentTarget == tombolMenu[i]){
                trace(jumlahFrame[i]);
                navi_mc.visible=true;
                TweenLite.from(navi_mc, 1, {delay:4, y:700});
                TweenLite.to(judulMateri[i], 1, {delay:3, x:89.45, y:36.45, ease:Back.easeOut});
                TweenLite.to(isiMateri[i], 1, {delay:3.4, x:392.45, y:246.95, ease:Back.easeOut});
                navi_mc.next_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_next);
                navi_mc.prev_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_prev);
                //navi_mc.home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_home);
                navi_mc.prev_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                navi_mc.home_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                navi_mc.prev_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                navi_mc.home_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                //tombol next
                function fl_next(e:MouseEvent):void{
                    for(var i:int = 0; i<= isiMateri.length; i++){
                        isiMateri[i].nextFrame();
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame == 2 ){
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                        }
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame == jumlahFrame[i]){
                            trace(isiMateri[i].currentFrame);
                            navi_mc.next_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                            navi_mc.next_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                        }
                    }                   
                }
                //tombol prev
                function fl_prev(e:MouseEvent):void{
                    for(var i:int = 0; i<= isiMateri.length; i++){
                        isiMateri[i].prevFrame();
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame == 1){
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                            navi_mc.next_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.next_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                        }
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame==(jumlahFrame[i] - 1)){
                            navi_mc.next_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.next_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //tombol home
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone helps :)
thank you everyone

Comment: You should only show the problematic code.

Comment: I don't know where the error code located, thats why I copied all of them, :D. I really don't get it where is my error code located

Comment: Install flash player debugger, you will be able to see the number of code line where error occured. http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: First, this is the error: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. not the one you put in topic, also if you dont have greensock code where this error manifests you will not have line number (it can be not allowed to debug) and anyway you will not be able to modify it anyway. I would try to first locate the 'null' possibly you feed one of greensock methods with reference to not existing object, can you try and trace objects that you want to animate before calls to any of greensock methods? And of course use debug FP as it may give you the stack order within your code .

Answer (score 0):

sorry for slow respon :D

finally I found the problematic code

here it is, I get this error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at com.greensock::TweenLite/init() at com.greensock::TweenMax/init() at com.greensock::TweenMax/renderTime() at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime() at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
```

when I run this script

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<= tombolMenu.length; i++){
            var gaps:Number = i/4;
            //menu hilang
            TweenMax.to(tombolMenu[i], 1,{delay:gaps,scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Circ.easeIn});

            //munculkan materi
            if (e.currentTarget == tombolMenu[i]){
                trace(jumlahFrame[i]);
                navi_mc.visible=true;
                TweenLite.from(navi_mc, 1, {delay:4, y:700});
                TweenLite.to(judulMateri[i], 1, {delay:3, x:89.45, y:36.45, ease:Back.easeOut});
                TweenLite.to(isiMateri[i], 1, {delay:3.4, x:392.45, y:246.95, ease:Back.easeOut});
                navi_mc.next_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_next);
                navi_mc.prev_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_prev);
                //navi_mc.home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_home);
                navi_mc.prev_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                navi_mc.home_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                navi_mc.prev_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                navi_mc.home_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
```

and get this error

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at MethodInfo-258()
```

when run

```
function fl_next(e:MouseEvent):void{
                    for(var i:int = 0; i<= isiMateri.length; i++){
                        isiMateri[i].nextFrame();
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame == 2 ){
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.prev_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                        }
                        if(isiMateri[i].currentFrame == jumlahFrame[i]){
                            trace(isiMateri[i].currentFrame);
                            navi_mc.next_mc.alpha = 0.4;
                            navi_mc.next_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.alpha = 1;
                            navi_mc.home_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
                        }
```

the full code is in first post.
is something wrong with my array function to thw TweenLite action?